# Async downloads with NSURLConnection prove unreliable

Tags: ios, core-data, asynchronous, download, nsurlconnection

I have been using NSURLConnection to perform some async downloads. Basically I retrieve a PFFile from Parse backend and display it in a web view. I offer an option to download to device. Everything is good to go and all tasks perform as required, however, lately i've noticed if I perform downloads at a high rate of speed some of them don't show up in the Downloads VC. I don't know how to test it, but my theory is it's getting cut off because the priority is set to High, **EVEN THOUGH**, users can't do anything until the download is complete. You have to exit out of the current `UIWebView` to select another document. This isn't a consist behavior which makes it harder for me to narrow down. It only happens when I download > exit > open > & download another document right away > exit > repeat until done and there is no specific document it does it with.

***THE PROBLEM*** : downloads perform, and I get an NSLog of file created, however, when I go to the Downloads VC the document doesn't show up in the NSFRC, but still shows as a valid file in the directory.

**THE PROCESS**
How the download happens,

The UIWebView loads a PDF queried from Parse.com. No problem here.
A ProgressHUD displays

Once loaded the progressHUD goes away.

If they want to download the PDF they just click on the action sheet index for downloading and it starts the download process.

Another Progress HUD displays as you can see in the NSURL didReceiveData displays. This HUD does not allow user interaction until the download is complete. So you can't exit the View Controller to select another pdf until it's done completely done downloading. So **NO** i am not conducting numerous downloads simultaneously, it's one download at a time.

Then the user can exit after download complete, select another UITableViewCell which loads the respective PDF and repeats the process.

Loading the PDF :

```
PFQuery *EGQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Classname"];
    [EGQuery whereKey:@"KeyName" equalTo:self.title];
    [EGQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if ([object objectForKey:@"EGFile"]) {
                PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"EGFile"];
                self.pdfURL = [file url];
                self.pdfName = [file name]; //Ends up as EG_2014_04 this is what I append to the filePath where it's stored so the filePath will be /PDFs/EG_2014_04
                [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.pdfURL]]];
            } else {
            }
```

Download method :

```
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Downloads"];
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pubnumber = %@", self.title]];
        [request setFetchLimit:1];
        NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (count == NSNotFound) {

        } else if (count == 0) {

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pdfURL]; //pdfURL is PFFile url
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
               self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                    [connection start];
                    NSLog(@"Background time remaining = %.1f seconds", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
               }];
                NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc]
                                   initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.pdfURL]];

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFs"];
                NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.pdfName];

                NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                [fm createFileAtPath:filePath contents:pdfData attributes:nil];
                if ([fm createFileAtPath:filePath contents:pdfData attributes:nil])
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSManagedObject *newDWNLD = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Downloads" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    [newDWNLD setValue:self.title forKey:@"pubnumber"];
                    [newDWNLD setValue:self.pubTitle forKey:@"pubtitle"];
                    [newDWNLD setValue:self.pdfName forKey:@"puburl"]; // this is what I use for the file path name in the PDF directory and this is how I call it in my NSFRC
                    });
                    NSLog(@"File was created");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"File not created");
                }
            });

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    expectedLength = MAX([response expectedContentLength], 1);
    currentLength = 0;
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    HUD.labelText = @"Downloading...";
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
currentLength += [data length];
HUD.progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"success.png"]];
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
HUD.labelText = @"Success!";
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Added to Downloads";
HUD.dimBackground = YES;
[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1.6];
//Cancel Background task if completed
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
//self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
[HUD hide:YES];
}
```

**DOWNLOADS VC**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Downloads" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:50];

NSSortDescriptor *azSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pubnumber" ascending:YES];
NSArray *azSortArray = @[azSort];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:azSortArray];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"pubnumber" cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [context valueForKey:@"pubnumber"]];
cell.textLabel.text = title;
etc etc
```

**EDIT** It seems to download all of them, and 'creates' a file, however it doesn't display all of them in the VC.

`application DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
NSString *createPaths;
NSArray *documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
createPaths = [[documents objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDFs"];
 NSLog(@"PDFs directory: %@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:createPaths error:&error]);
```

The above accrucately logs all the files that I downloaded, but they just aren't either getting recognized as fully downloaded from the UIWebView or creating the file path is going awry somehow during the download process so it's not displaying in the downloads view controller but the other documents do show up. It's consistently 1-2 missing from each session but like i stated before, its never the same document missing, it's whatever feels like missing is missing. Say I download 10 then close the app then re open it 9 will only be there in the Downloads VC sometimes 8, but it logs as being a valid filePath in the directory.

Comment: Are you logging errors? Presumably you start getting timeouts...

Comment: @Wain most of the downloads are a 1-3MB, and there is no user interaction allowed until the download is complete. I have `connection:didFailWithError:` implemented but it never gets called because it always finishes, creates the file in NSFileManger, but doesn't populate in the Downloads VC. And as you can see I don't add any keys/values to the Core Data Entity unless the file was created

Comment: @Wain in other words, I haven't been getting errors because the response times is relatively efficient with wi-fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be your managed object context thread confinement, specifically you aren't confining. You get the context on the original thread, presumably the main thread, but then you capture it in the background block and access it directly.

You should take the result of saving your file and send it back to the main thread, then create and save the new managed object there.

Comment: I knew you were gonna say that ;) I tried prior to posting the question but I may have missed something. You seem to know what your doing so I'll give it another go tomorrow. Midnight here.

Comment: just re-tested processing it through the main thread with same results. The file creates but doesn't populate in Downloads VC  while others do- any ideas on where to go from here? does it have anything to do with the background task?

Comment: How is the downloads vc getting the data?

Comment: Just a normal fetched results controller. I don't think that's issue because it displays the document just not when I download them fast m. I'll update my question when I get home though with the code. I just haven't had any problems with it until I implemented the background task so if they close the app the download continues. I'll include that as well

Comment: I have edited my question. It's becoming clear to me that I don't know what i'm doing ha. It has nothing to do with starting an finite-length background task and creating it in the main thread resulted in the same circumstances

Comment: I just don't know how to actually convey what's happening @Wain I hope the point is clear and concise?

Comment: Ok, from your description you are starting all the downloads (many at once), then closing the app (while still running), then waiting and reopening. Is this correct? Connected to Xcode? Have you checked all the files are *fully* downloaded? reading your code again your url connection delegate methods will never be called as you aren't using one. So any download could fail and you wouldn't know about it (and save empty file).

Comment: Thank for your patience @Wain i completely restructured my question so hopefully it is clear and concise now, I included anything and everything thats relevant or not, so at least its there. But no, downloads don't happen simultaneously, neither are there numerous downloads, it's one download per visit to the UIWebView since each launch of that UIWebView is for a different PDF. The background task is there just in case if the user does close the app during the download process it will continue instead of terminate.

Comment: How would you recommend I check a file is fully downloaded?  as opposed to just the filePath name getting created in the directory? Even so if it wasn't fully downloaded why wouldn't the Core Data Entity get updated because the filePath is still being 'created'?

Comment: I am invested in starting a bounty for this so if you can answer it prior to me initiating the bounty I will gladly award it to you, i'm not trying to rush you or anything just giving you aheads up

Comment: Can you show the code you tried to move things back to the main thread. Agree with you that even if an empty file is saved it should update core data. You said you open and close many web views, so you will have many downloads at once. Also, the web view does one download and you're also doing another one explicitly? Or `self.pdfURL` is a local file URL?

Comment: sorry for the delays, i'm in Alaska on alaskan time!  self.pdfURL is the http:// link for the PFFile, so the webView loads that after the query retrieves it. It was typo in the query. You can see `self.pdfURL = [file url]` which will inevitably be the downloaded file if they want to download it. Locally downloaded pdfs are opened with a different PDF reader (more feature rich) in  a different VC. I also added the main queue to the managed object as you requested (also i'm under the impression NSFileManager is thread safe so thats why i didn't put it there)

Comment: Technically you should create a new instance of `NSFileManager` for each thread rather than use the `defaultManager IIRC.

Comment: ___OOPS___ that's quite embarrassing. Please update your answer with the save context discrepancy, also, i think the NSFileManager thread point you provided is worthy to include as well. Thanks for your patience I really appreciate you, and this was the only hindrance to me submitting this for review. I will award you the bounty as promised -

Comment: Damn, that was in your original answer :/ sorry for the run around

Comment: I can't start a bounty from my iPhone app but i'll do it once I get home from work, but interim, any theories why it was even allowing to add new objects without saving and retaining a majority of those objects?

Comment: You must have a save trigger somewhere, perhaps in the app delegate, perhaps when the app goes to the background, which wouldn't be called after a background task finished.

Comment: I can't award it to you for another 23 hours - thanks again for your patience and undivided attention. It really means a lot to me